# Blazor Web Site keeps reloading randomly every few seconds

Tags: asp.net, iis, blazor

I have a Blazor Web Site that keeps reloading every few sconds. this occurs on the customer server prod env. but not in the local development env. also the problem didn't appear right from the begining. it was stable until one of the recent version updates. any ideas ?

I've read that sometimes this a Chrome beheaviour that sends releoad request

Comment: Is it Blazor server-side or Blazor WASM?

Comment: We need more information: Is it normal on other browser except Chrome? Are you using Blazor server or Blazor WASM? Which version did you update to? Besides, I found an issue described Blazor WASM keep reload after upgrade from .net5 to .net6 on Firefox Browser, [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39305). The reason for that problem is out of memory. That happens when the Blazor WASM app size is too large. You would find request logs on IIS logging files if the refreshing is a browser behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved
EventAggregator.Blazor was it.
crazy bug and missused 3th part component.
I used it to send events from diffrent pages/components to top area of the view like status messages etc.
It seems to work well.
But then when in prodution we opened the site to many users, it turns out that every request a user sends, is notified to the rest of the current active users and causes their browser to refres.